# image in html hiding under nav bar in header

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have downloaded an html template and it has a banner after the nav bar, i am trying to replace the image banner with my image, i changed it to the same size of the image in the template and added, the html is like below:

```html
<div class="single-creative-shop-banner parallaxBg bg-img" style="max-width:100%; height:auto;"
         data-bg="assets/img/home-banner/home_shop_creative_01.jpg">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                    <div class="creative-shop-banner-content">
                        <h2>Minimal Collection</h2>
                        <p class="mb-0">Unlock The Goddess In You</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

the css is so long , not able to post in the question, my website is https://likhaa.com

the problem is when i am adding the banner image, its not properly displaying, instead some part is hiding under the navbar, and the width is also not proper. is there any code in html to fix it or can anyone help me with my code

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the inline margin of 131px from the div having the class "shop-creative-banner" also remove position fixed from the div which is children of div having id "jarallax-container-0"

Comment: wer did u find it, in css?

Comment: it is HTML, not in css

Comment: there is nothing like that in my html, no inline style is applied